# вставить пару изображений в input

Tags: css, css3

Верстаю главную страницу google,большого опыта не имею,дошел до создания формы ввода запроса и тут на тебе.Надо добавить три фотографии в `input`,значок поиска,клавиатуры и микрофона(думаю все знают как выглядит форма в гугле).Нарыл инфу о том,что можно для `input` прописать `background-image`,но тогда можно поместить только один значок в форму,а мне нужно 3.Подскажите как быть.

Comment: Чтобы получить ответ, нужно показать как вы пытались решить проблему. То, что вы понимаете, в чем недостаток решения, которое вы наши первым, это хорошо, но нужно чтобы вы показали, как вы попытались это преодолеть. Помощь тут добровольная, поэтому требовать финального решения некорректно.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы верстаете главную страницу гугла, то предлагаю, прежде всего, посмотреть как это реализовано у них, а не браться за свой велосипед. Сделать это можно используя Chrome Dev Tools (если используете Chrome, но у всех современных браузеров есть что-то подобное).

Если упрощенно, то у гугла этот компонент сверстан примерно вот так:

```html
<div id="search-component">
  <div id="icon-search"></div>
  <div id="search-input">
    <input>
  </div>
  <div id="icon-mic"></div>
</div>
```

Такое решение позволит сделать микрофон кнопкой без особых проблем, если требуется.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы не поверите, но КАЖДОЕ из CSS-свойств, относящихся к фону, поддерживает множественные значения через запятую.
2. Запихайте инпут и кнопки в ряд в общий контейнер. Сделайте инпуту фон прозрачным, а бордеры уберите вообще. Обстильте сам контейнер вместо инпута, ну и кнопки независимо.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray inset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  border: 0px none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: none;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."></input>
  <div class="button search">Search</div>
  <div class="button voice">Voice</div>
  <div class="button photo">Photo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Вроде бы решил,можно указать вместо `background-image` просто `background` и через запятую перечислить URL на изображение.Вот как оно выглядит у меня:

```css
background: url("media/img/search.png")no-repeat 10px 7px,url("media/img/keyboard.png") no-repeat 470px 6px,url("media/img/microphone.png") no-repeat 510px 8px;
background-size: 23px;
```

**P.S тем не менее,цели я пока не добился,значок поиска стоит как и должен,а вот значок клавиатуры и микрофона должны быть кнопками,как это реализовать я пока не знаю:)**